# Como guardar una imagen desde vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Hola estoy subiendo una foto desde Vue
pero me la pone en base64 entonces intente decodificarla para tratar la imagen.

así es como tengo mi controlador

```html
  public function Update (ValidatePersonalRequest $request)
{


 if($request->foto)
      {
         $foto  = base64_decode($request->foto);

         $request->foto = $foto;
        
         $url = request()->file('foto')->store('p','public');


         $request['foto'] = $url;

         auth()->user()->update($request->all());


         return 'ok';

      }


   auth()->user()->update($request->all()):
}
```

En resumen

```
  : Necesito validar que la imagen sea una imagen.
  : Que lo que reciba en el request viene una imagen si no no hacer nada
  : Guardarla
```

Pero no me funciona las validaciones, ya que como es base 64 me dice que es un string. Y pues no sirve de nada poner validate  . .  image|max:2045

Answer (score 3):

Yo pase un buen rato tratando de resolver este dilema de imágenes base64 y lo que hice fue lo siguiente:

El formulario:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" accept="image/*" @change="onFileChanged($event)">
</form>
```

La función del input:

```
 onFileChanged: function(event) {
  var file = event.target.files[0]; // Se obtiene la imagen desde el evento.
  var fileSize = event.target.files[0].size // Se obtiene el tamaño de la imagen.
  // Se valida que el tamaño de la imagen sea el admitido.
  if (fileSize > 1001024) {
      this.companyLogoError = "La imagen no debe pesar mas de 1MB, por favor introduzca una nueva";
      this.data.logo = null;
  } else { // Si el tamaño es valido, seguimos.
      this.companyLogoError = "" // No se muestra el mensaje de error

      let reader = new FileReader(); //El objeto FileReader permite que las aplicaciones web lean ficheros
      reader.onload = (event) => { // Este evento se activa cada vez que la operación de lectura se ha completado satisfactoriamente.
        this.data.logo = event.target.result
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file); // Comienza la lectura del contenido del objeto Blob
  }
}
```

El controlador en Laravel:

```
 public function update(CompanyUpdateRequest $request, $id)
{
        $company = Company::find($id);

       if ($request->logo) {
            $logo = $request->logo;  //Se obtienen los datos de la imagen desde la solicitud.
            $ext = explode(";", $logo); // Se dividen los datos, en este caso se obtiene la informacion antes del ";" "data:image/jpeg;".
            $ext = str_replace('data:image/', '', $ext); // Se reemplazan los datos "data:image/" por vacio para generar una nueva cadena y obtener la extension de la imagen "jpeg".
            $ext = $ext[0]; // En este punto $ext es un arreglo de datos, por lo tanto la extension de la imagen se encuentra en la primera posicion "0".
            $logo = str_replace('data:image/'. $ext .';base64,', '', $logo); // Se elimina la data inicial de la imagen para luego ser decodificada.
            $logo = base64_decode($logo); //Se decodifica la data de la imagen recibida.
            $logoName = str_random(20).'.'. $ext; // Se asigna un nombre a la imagen recibida.
            Storage::disk('uploads')->put($logoName, $logo); // Se almacena la imagen en public/uploads/image.ext
            $request->logo = $logoName;
        }
        else {
            $request->logo = "default-user.png";
        }

        DB::table('companies')
            ->where('id', $id)
            ->update([
                'user_id' => $request->user_id,
                'name' => $request->name,
                'ruc' => $request->ruc,
                'address' => $request->address,
                'logo' => $request->logo,
                'phone' => $request->phone,
                'contact' => $request->contact,
                'email' => $request->email,
        ]);
}
```

En resumen: Validamos que solo sean imagenes en el input con la propiedad accept="image/*", en onFileChanged: function(event), obtenemos la imagen, validamos su peso y la procesamos y en el controlador procesamos el string que nos llega desde vuejs(la explicación del procesamiento esta indicado)..

Disculpa si se ve desordenado pero es mi primer post, espero te solucione!

Answer (score 0):

Aunque base64 sea un string, para validar que sea una imagen, te bastaría con comprobar el comienzo de ese string...
Ya que sería de esta manera:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAABAQQABAA...
```

Entonces, capturaríamos el tipo:

```
$data = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAABAQQABAA.';
$posicion  = strpos($data, ';');
$tipo = explode(':', substr($data, 0, $posicion))[1];
```

Para guardar la imagen que viene en base64, podrías usar *make*

```
Image::make(file_get_contents($request->foto))->store('p','public');     
    $respuesta = array(
        'status' => 'success',
    );
    return Response::json($respuesta);
```

Un saludo.